# Magento column layout issue

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I'm having some trouble trying to get Magento to display just my products without specific blocks being displayed. If you visit http://bit.ly/HVeAlD you can see the left hand categories, the center product display and the right hand column blocks with compare products and paypal.

I, for the life of me, can't determine why Magento has decided to randomly begin rendering the page with the right hand column. My page layout is set to 2 column with left bar (the Default Category is) and all the children in my category structure are set to use parent.

If someone can guide me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in \layout\catalog.xml

find catalog_category_default

add

```
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
```